# Make Toolbar in NestedScrollView not scrollable

Tags: android, scrollview, android-toolbar, android-nestedscrollview, nestedscrollview

I have a custom `Toolbar` inside a `NestedScrollView`.
In the `NestedScrollView` are also some `TextViews` and `Edittexts`.

My problem is that not only the `TextViews` and `Edittexts` are scrolled, the `Toolbar` is scrolled too.

It is only logical that a `Toolbar` in a `NestedScrollView` is scrolled.

I want a custom `Toolbar` with an absolute position at the top and scrollable `TextViews` and `Edittexts`.

This is the code I am working at:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:contentInsetEnd="50dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="50dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="A long unimportant text"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

So I tried to wrap only the `TextViews` and `Edittexts` in a `ScrollView` like:

```
        <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:contentInsetEnd="50dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="50dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="A long unimportant text"/>

                </ScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>
```

But it's not working.

> It's **very** important that a **custom** `Toolbar` is used.

Comment: have a look at collapse toolbar.?

Comment: you didn't close the toolbar  
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

Comment: @Veener I just forgot it in the question, but not in my code. But thanks anyway for the hint, I edited my question.

Comment: Do you have more than one TextView inside your ScrollView?

Comment: Just to be sure... In your second approach where you wrapped the TextView in scroll view, is whole layout wrapped inside nestedScroll or the linear layout is root layout? @Jakob

Comment: @BenP. Yes a lot of TextViews and Edittexts, wrapped in Linear Layouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a relative layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".EmptyActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:contentInsetEnd="50dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="50dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="A long unimportant text" />

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: As Ben P states in his answer, it is worth mentioning that the ScrollView must have one direct child. So if you have more than one TextView you will need to wrap it in another layout.

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollView` (and `NestedScrollView`) will *allow* you to add multiple direct children to them, but in order for them to work properly, they must have exactly one direct child. So, wrap the contents of your `ScrollView` in a `wrap_content` LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="A long unimportant text"/>

            <!-- many more views -->

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```